# Ajax call getting canceled in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, jquery-ui

component1 have iframe of component2

in component1 i am calling x() onclick in anchor tag.

x() opens iframe of component2 in jquery modal.

then x() calls 1 of the component2 fuction which includes AJAX request

But AJAX request getting cancelled.

Tried solutions - e.preventDedault(), return false.

Tried solutions - e.preventDedault(), return false.

Comment: you may be *doing something wrong™* in your code - usually it's line 37 that's the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you use sandbox attribute in your iframe tag ? cause that can prevent your iframe from accessing top level context using javascript